# C++ how to query value outside the callback arduino

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-c++

I want that the measurement interval and MQTT server settings can be changed from cellphone by BLE. I use LightBlue as a mobile application.

Here is my BLE code that works well with my mobile application

```
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"
class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
    void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
      std::string value = pCharacteristic->getValue();
      if (value.length() > 0) {
        Serial.println("*********");
        Serial.print("New value: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++)
          Serial.print(value[i]);

        Serial.println();
        Serial.println("*********");
      }
    }
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("1- Download and install an BLE scanner app in your phone");
  Serial.println("2- Scan for BLE devices in the app");
  Serial.println("3- Connect to MyESP32");
  Serial.println("4- Go to CUSTOM CHARACTERISTIC in CUSTOM SERVICE and write something");
  Serial.println("5- See the magic =)");

  BLEDevice::init("MyESP32");
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();

  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                                         CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
                                       );

  pCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());

  pCharacteristic->setValue("Hello World");
  pService->start();

  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->start();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(2000);
}
```

This is MQTT code :

```
void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  // Every X number of seconds (interval = 10 seconds) 
  // it publishes a new MQTT message
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    // Save the last time a new reading was published
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    // New DHT sensor readings
    hum = dht.readHumidity();
    // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
    temp = dht.readTemperature();
    // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
    //temp = dht.readTemperature(true);    

    // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
    if (isnan(temp) || isnan(hum)) {
      Serial.println(F("Failed to read from DHT sensor!"));
      return;
    }
    
    // Publish an MQTT message on topic esp32/dht/temperature
    uint16_t packetIdPub1 = mqttClient.publish(MQTT_PUB_TEMP, 1, true, String(temp).c_str());                            
    Serial.printf("Publishing on topic %s at QoS 1, packetId: %i", MQTT_PUB_TEMP, packetIdPub1);
    Serial.printf("Message: %.2f \n", temp);

    // Publish an MQTT message on topic esp32/dht/humidity
    uint16_t packetIdPub2 = mqttClient.publish(MQTT_PUB_HUM, 1, true, String(hum).c_str());                            
    Serial.printf("Publishing on topic %s at QoS 1, packetId %i: ", MQTT_PUB_HUM, packetIdPub2);
    Serial.printf("Message: %.2f \n", hum);
  }
}
```

Please how I can set the interval to whichever variable from the BLE code instead of 10000.

```
long interval = 10000;
```

Comment: Have you tried just assigning the new value to `interval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your variable *interval* as global variable to access it from everywhere in your file. A global variable can be declared outside of functions.

The value you receive is of type std::string and you want to use it as long. You can use [toInt()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/toint/) to convert the variable from String to Long.

Try something like this:

```
long interval = 10000; // Set default value

class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
    void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
      std::string value = pCharacteristic->getValue();
      if (value.length() > 0) {
        Serial.println("*********");
        Serial.print("New value: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++)
          Serial.print(value[i]);

        Serial.println();
        Serial.println("*********");
        interval = value.toInt(); // <-- Set received value
      }
    }
};
```